# Query firebase database and retrieve from 2 nodes

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve from firebase database and I already have setup my model to put content in place. I succeeded to retrieve data from one single node but I am unable to do so where I need data from 2 nodes which I want to show it in say Recycler View. However, where I get the success is completely different fragment.

First, I will show you my code for retrieving data from just one node and it is working for me.

Here's the code which is working for one node in different fragment.

**Working-Fragment**

```
    private void updateArrayList() {        

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_posts))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            data.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Userpost.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Above Code works perfectly.
Now **Non-Working Code** which doesn't pull anything.

```
    private void updateArrayList() {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_posts)).child("profile_photo")
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .child("profile_photo");

    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            data.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Userpost.class));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

This is a snapshot for firebase database
[Firebase Database Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK8bG.png)

I made the question as clear as possible on my end. 
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get those values from a specific post, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference postIdRef = rootRef.child("posts").child(postId);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String pheading = dataSnapshot.child("pheading").getValue(String.class);
        String user_id = dataSnapshot.child("user_id").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", pheading + " / " + user_id);

        DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("user_account_settings").child(user_id);
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
                String profile_photo = ds.child("profile_photo").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", profile_photo);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
postIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `postId` is the id of the post from which you want to extract the data.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned I also want to retrieve data at same time from another node "user_account_settings" on a child which is (user_id) under "posts" node. Please take a look at the screenshot I added in my questions. PS. thanks for helping me out